# Exception during overriding onStop() to show ad

Tags: android

I want to show an interstitial ad during user presses back/home or recent app button. As all action goes via onStop() method, so i did call the ad like this

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
        mInterstitialAd.show();         
        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                // do nothing

            }
        });
    }else{
        super.onStop();
    }       
}
```

But I am getting exception `E/AndroidRuntime(26313): Caused by: android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {package.name...} did not call through to super.onStop()

Intention is during those pressing button, if ad is loaded then show, else call super to proceed.
**What I am doing wrong ?** Any other approach ?

Comment: Am I right that you are thinking of showing an ad to the user when they try to _leave_ your app (back/home or recent app)? You should reconsider. [The documentation](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6201362?hl=en-GB&ref_topic=2745287) specifically warns against breaking the natural user experience.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `super.onStop` in all cases. Change your code as below

```
    @Override
    protected void onStop () {
        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
            mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAdClosed() {
                    // do nothing
                }
            });
        }
        super.onStop();
    }
```

Comment: great man...no error...but my ad is not viewed..i given a sysout inside isLoaded() and it prints, but did not showed my ad... :( pls help

Comment: onStop is called when activity activity is no longer visible to the user. You should move your ad thing to onResume. Also there must be some listener to listen for the ad loading use them to know exactly when ad is loaded.

Comment: `onStop()` is not meant to be used as a place to show ads, the system is trying to close the activity down and may even destroy it if it needs to. This is the place to save your apps state or user's entered form data into the db or releasing objects for GC.

Comment: HI Manish, I know that onResume is called when an app is starting, but I want to show when user leaves it, like Facebook, Whatsapp etc shows an interstitial ad when user presses those button...

Comment: in That case override the back key and listen for the event as soon as you get back for the first time show the ad if you get back again pass it to the system. onStop is not the right choice to show it.

Comment: I am trying now with back button....but technically ad show on onStop() is possible...but not showing :(

Comment: Manish, back button works...but still thinking why not onStop() or onPause() :(  I mean the technical reason.

Comment: Technically onStop is called when your activity is no longer visible to the user so its not the best place to push anything in front of the user.

Comment: My thought is before the super is called, we can hold the app's visibiliy by not calling super and showing the ad, now when the user ends the add by back/home, then we will call the super...

Comment: probably FB, Whatspp, others app showing ad only at back button, not home button..thx Manish

Comment: You can't skip the call to super as system has check to make sure you call super else it will throw exception.